# How to migrate private existing domain to aws EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having a private domain how can I migrate it to AWS EC2. The example I am having a website www.exmaplesoft.com and this is already in running condition I want this to be migrated to AWS EC2.

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to point an existing domain (managed somewhere else) to point to an Amazon EC2 server, or would you like to transfer management of the domain to Amazon Route 53 (which is the AWS DNS service)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be sure whether you are migrating your server, or domain management. If you want to transfer domain, you can check out [Transferring Registration for a Domain to Amazon Route 53 - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html).

If you are looking to migrate your server, then the work is highly dependent on how you have deployed your server.